# What is Purpose of @using in BeginForm

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{}
```

> So in the above 'beginform' why we write @using why we don't directly write    @Html.BeginForm()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the `@using (Html.BeginForm())` implicitly calls `@Html.EndForm` at the end of the `using`.

So an equivalent of the `using` construction would be:

```
@Html.BeginForm()

...

@Html.EndForm()
```

Comment: @KartikeyaKhosla: Need more help?